# SemanticZoom's ToggleActiveView method throws AccessViolationException

Tags: xaml, gridview, uwp, igrouping, semantic-zoom

I have a `GridView` in a UWP app that does not contain grouped items.  So I can't just put it in a `SemanticZoom` and have the headers be used as toggles to "zoom out" to a jump list.  Instead, I am relying on 1) touch-screen users to pinch-zoom and 2) a command button that toggles the semantic zoom.

The pinch-zoom action works.  My jumplist `GridView` of first letter items is shown and I handle the `SemanticZoom`'s `ViewChangeStarted` event to scroll to the correct item in the original, zoomed-in GridView.

However, when I use a commandbar button to switch from zoomed-in to zoomed-out using the built-in method `ToggleActiveView`, it immediately throws an AccessViolationException.

**Does anyone know what is going on?**

Is it broken because I'm not using grouped items in the zoomed-in list?  My zoomed-in gridview datasource is a list of my model items.  That's it.  For the zoomed-out gridview, I'm using an Linq method that selects the first character in the display name of all of my model items.  This *is* returned as an `IEnumerable<IGrouping<string,object>>`.  Doing it this way allows me to easily get the first item for that letter and scroll to the appropriate item in the zoomed-in list.

Comment: I can't give you the reason base on your describe，. You can post the code or see the sample for [SemanticZoom](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/XamlUIBasics).

Comment: did you ever find a solution for this?